# Table cells are not the same height within row

Tags: html, css

I am creating a table in html. Every table cell needs to be *exactly* the same height. When I put a div in the table cell the height is not the same between table cells in the row. The table cells that contain text are 61.6px tall while the table cells that contain divs are 61.2px tall. I am using Google Chrome and that is the only browser I need the table cells to be an even height for. How do I ensure all the table cells are the same height?

A pure CSS solution is preferred but a javascript solution is acceptable.

```css
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 600px;
    }

    tbody {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    th {
        padding: 0 6px;
        text-align: center;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }

    tr td {
        background: darkgray;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) td {
        background: gray;
    }

    td.small {
        font-size: 9px;
    }

    td.large {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

    td {
        padding: 6px;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 0 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        height: 18px;
    }

    .evilobject {
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Large Font</th>
            <th>Small Font</th>
            <th>Contains Div</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: In your example, all the cells have the same height. Also, screens can't present a fraction of a pixel, a pixel is the smallest size that can be presented so maybe you see a raw result that is being rounded later

Comment: I am using this code in an electron application. When run a visible split can be seen in the table. I am assuming this is because of the native windows scaling applied to my window. The only solution I can think of to prevent that from happening is to have all cells be the exact same height.

Answer (score 0):

Use tr instead of td and use universal selector`

```css
*{
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
table {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 600px;
    }

    tbody {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }

    th {
        padding: 0 6px;
        text-align: center;
        background: black;
        color: white;
    }

    tr td {
        background: darkgray;
    }

    tr:nth-child(even) td {
        background: gray;
    }

    td.small {
        font-size: 9px;
    }

    td.large {
        font-size: 18px;
    }

     tr{
        padding: 6px;
        border-color: black;
        border-width: 0 1px;
        border-style: solid;
        height: 18px;
       
    }

    .evilobject {
        height: 50px;
        background: red;
    }
```

```html
<table >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Large Font</th>
            <th>Small Font</th>
            <th>Contains Div</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="large">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small">What the font!?</td>
            <td class="small"><div class="evilobject">Evil div object</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

`